# How i can add "ServerName xxx" in httpd.conf through chef / vagrant

Tags: apache, centos, chef-infra, vagrant

I'm playing with a vagrant Centos 6.4 box,

here's the relevant part of my Vagrantfile

```
  config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
    chef.json = {
        "apache" => {
            "listen_address" => "0.0.0.0",
            "server_name" => "localhost", # ?? this doesn't work
        },
    }
    chef.add_recipe "yum"
    chef.add_recipe "selinux::disabled"
    chef.add_recipe "vim"
    # chef.add_recipe "openssl"
    chef.add_recipe "apache2"
    chef.add_recipe "php"
    chef.add_recipe "php::module_curl"
    chef.add_recipe "php::module_mysql"
    chef.add_recipe "apache2::mod_php5"
    chef.add_recipe "apache2::mod_rewrite"
    chef.add_recipe "my"
  end
```

Unfortunately when i do `vagrant provision` i get some errors because apache doesn't start properly. The error is `httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using localhost.localdomain for ServerName`

If i do `vagrant ssh` then i can fix it adding `ServerName localhost` to the httpd.conf (/var/httpd/conf/httpd.conf) and httpd service starts properly.

**How can I add this as attribute in `chef.json`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is usually caused when your server doesn't know its own Fully Qualified Domain Name... Try setting this with the vagrant command hostname:

```
config.vm.hostname = "server.name"
```

See this page for more details: http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/vagrantfile/machine_settings.html